# Pagebreaks and parskip with lots of small sections

Tags: page-breaking, parskip

I'm having trouble with page breaks in a LaTeX document. LaTeX seems to occasionally (and inexplicably) move a few lines onto a new page, even when there is clearly enough room for those lines at the bottom of the previous page.

I've been able to work out that changing the `parskip` value will change the behaviour. In the MWE below, using the default value for `\parskip` pushes a whole section onto a new page. Changing the `\parskip` to exactly 0 causes everything to fit on one page (the default `\parskip` seems to be `0pt plus 1pt`). Alternately, changing the parskip to something like `0pt plus 4pt minus 1pt` causes four whole sections to appear on the second page. *Note that the actual paragraph spacing in the produced document does not change at all.*

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,oneside]{article} 
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage[showframe,
    left=10pc,
    right=5pc,
    top=5.5pc,
    bottom=5pc,
    marginparwidth=6pc,
  ]{geometry} % Adjust page margins

\setlength{\parskip}{0pt plus 4pt minus 1pt} % Many lines go to next page
% \setlength{\parskip}{0pt} % Everything fits on one page.

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  [leftmargin]{\footnotesize\vspace{0pt}\filleft}{}{.5em}{}
\titlespacing{\subsection}
  {4pc}{0.2ex plus .1ex minus .1ex}{1pc}

\begin{document}
\raggedbottom
\setlength{\parindent}{0pc} % Remove paragraph indentation

\the\parskip

\foreach \n in {7:30,8:00,8:30,9:00,9:30,10:00,10:30,11:00,11:30,12:00,12:30,13:00,13:30,14:00,14:30,15:00,15:30,16:00,16:30,17:00,17:30,18:00,18:30,19:00,19:30,20:30,21:30}{
  \subsection{\n}\textbf{Time now is \n}\par Let's get busy!\par}

\end{document}
```

Result of MWE:

[image: PDF from MWE]

Answer (score 2):

That's imho a bug in the titlesec command used for the `leftmargin` option. It removes from `\pagegoal` the current `\pagestretch` value, and with a positiv stretch value in `\parskip` this piles up. If I remove this line your document compiles fine:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage[showframe,
    left=10pc,
    right=5pc,
    top=5.5pc,
    bottom=5pc,
    marginparwidth=6pc,
  ]{geometry} % Adjust page margins

\setlength{\parskip}{0pt plus 4pt minus 1pt} % Many lines go to next page
% \setlength{\parskip}{0pt} % Everything fits on one page.

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  [leftmargin]{\footnotesize}{}{.5em}{}
\titlespacing{\subsection}
  {4pc}{0.2ex plus .1ex minus .1ex}{1pc}


\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\ttlh@leftmargin{\advance\@tempskipa\pagestretch}{}{}{\fail}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\raggedbottom
\setlength{\parindent}{0pc} % Remove paragraph indentation

\the\parskip

\foreach \n in {7:30,8:00,8:30,9:00,9:30,10:00,10:30,11:00,11:30,12:00,12:30,13:00,13:30,14:00,14:30,15:00,15:30,16:00,16:30,17:00,17:30,18:00,18:30,19:00,19:30,20:30,21:30}{
  \subsection{\n}\textbf{Time now is \n}\par Let's get busy!\par}

\end{document}
```